# Getting an syntax error while trying to pivot a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

Difficulty faced: I am not able to figure out to solve the error.

Problem: Pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.

Table Occupations with Name(string), Occupation(string) as columns

My code:

```
Select Actor, Singer, Professor, Doctor from (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY NAME) as RowNumber, name, occupation FROM OCCUPATIONS
) as src
Pivot 
(
    min(name)
    for occupation in ([Actor], [Singer], [Professor], [Doctor])

) as pivottable;
```

error output:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check >the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right >syntax to use near '
>
> ```
> Pivot 
> (
>    min(name)
>    for occupation in ([Actor], [Singer], [Professor], [D
> ```
>
> ' at line 4

Comment: MySQL does not support PIVOT. This is MS SQL (SQL Server) syntax.

Comment: Provide table structure, data sample & expected output. There are alternative ways to do pivoting in MySQL.